# How to use dynamic style in vueJs

Tags: datepicker, vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

Is there a way to read data as props in vueJs component and use as value of < style > section?

something like :

```
<my-component color="red" />
```

and to use red as a dynamic value inside < style > section of component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-bind` can help you with dynamic styling in vue.js as explained [here][1].

> The object syntax for v-bind:style is pretty straightforward - it looks almost like CSS, except it’s a JavaScript object. You can use either camelCase or kebab-case (use quotes with kebab-case) for the CSS property names:

**HTML**

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
```

**vue instance**

```
data: {
  activeColor: 'red',
  fontSize: 30
}
```

Now `activeColor` is reactive here, whenever you change `activeColor` it will change in the HTML/CSS as well.
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

Comment: I want to use data value inside <style></style> section.

like : 

<style>
      .className { 
                    color: color-data
       }
</style>

Comment: @SaJed I dont think that is possible, whats possible is you can have different CSS classes and you can change those classes dynamically as explained [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

Comment: actually I'm useing datepicker which I need to override its classes to match with my theme color

Comment: I have hardcoded this class and it works fine but can't make it flexible:
.calendar .cell.highlighted { 
 color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #4f8fcc!important;
}


#4f8fcc should set with props value

Comment: @SaJed I am using [vue-datepicker](https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-datepicker) where I can send color etc in the option variable.

Comment: ah im using this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker
need to change it

Answer (score -2):

Be aware that for CSS properties that have "-" in like background-color you will need to write it slightly different to meet JS object style. Since json object definition format  does not allow - in name.

this will work

```
v-bind:style="{ 'background-color':backgroundColor }"
```

this will NOT work

```
v-bind:style="{ backgroundcolor:backgroundColor }"
```

chaos all the way from Pakistan. :)